# The Function that Changes the Texture Only Works Once

Tags: jquery, three.js

I have a skybox that the camera is placed inside of. When the buttons at the top of the page are pressed the textures of the box should change.

The box starts as mountain textures, and the city button successfully changes the textures to a city. But, the mountain button does not revert the textures.

```
    var mountain =
        [
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104320/RightMountain.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Right side
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104320/LeftMountain.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Left side
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104320/TopMountain.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Top side
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104320/BottomMountain.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Bottom side
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104320/FrontMountain.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Front side
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104314/BackMountain.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) // Back side
        ];

var city =
        [
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104616/FrontCity.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Front
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104616/BackCity.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Back
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104616/UpCity.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Up
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104616/DownCity.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Down
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104616/RightCity.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Right
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'https://res.cloudinary.com/egoldman15/image/upload/v1518104616/LeftCity.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) // Left
        ];

var cubeMaterials = mountain;

        // Create a MeshFaceMaterial, which allows the cube to have different materials on each face
//Changes the boxes material, color and image structure.


$('#city').click(function() {
  console.log('city');
  cubeMaterials = city;
  drawCube();
});
$('#mountain').click(function() {
  console.log('mountain');
  cubeMaterials = mountain;
  drawCube();
});

function drawCube() {
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, cubeMaterials );
  scene.add( cube );
}

drawCube();
```

Full code: https://codepen.io/egoldman15/pen/qxqJae

Comment: Just in case, [`scene.background`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/scenes/Scene.background) can be set to a cube texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example with `scene.background` and a cube texture:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var path = "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/SwedishRoyalCastle/";
var format = '.jpg';
var urls = [
  path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
  path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
  path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
];
var cubeTexture1 = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(urls);
cubeTexture1.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
scene.background = cubeTexture1;

var r = "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/cube/Park3Med/";
var urls = [
  r + "px.jpg", r + "nx.jpg",
  r + "py.jpg", r + "ny.jpg",
  r + "pz.jpg", r + "nz.jpg"
];
var cubeTexture2 = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(urls);

btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  scene.background = cubeTexture1;
}, false);
btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  scene.background = cubeTexture2;
}, false);

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div style="position: absolute;">
  <button id="btn1">
    1
  </button>
  <button id="btn2">
    2
  </button>
</div>
```

And about your code. You can create a box once and then change its material by clicking the buttons instead of creating a new box on each click.